# How to stop ongoing Indexing in Sitecore?

Tags: indexing

We have started indexing contacts by using `Helpfulcore.AnalyticsIndexBuilder` due to some reason we would like to stop contact indexing forcefully. May I know how can we stop indexing in Sitecore.

Comment: this is for which version you want to stop

Answer (score 0):

To stop contact indexing from the external module you added to the solution which is `Helpfulcore.AnalyticsIndexBuilder` you need to **disable** the below config file.

`/App_Config/Include/Helpfulcore/Helpfulcore.AnalyticsIndexBuilder.config` (add extension as .disabled)

If you are using `Sitecore 8.2` Then to stop all contact Indexing you need to follow the below.

1. Go to the `\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config` file.
2. Set the `ContentSearch.Analytics.IndexAnonymousContacts` setting value to "false".

   `<setting name="ContentSearch.Analytics.IndexAnonymousContacts" value="false"/>`

If you are using Sitecore 9XP Then to stop all contact Indexing you need to follow the below.

1. Open the xConnect Search Indexer `sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml` configuration file. In a default on-premise deployment, the full path is

`\<xConnect role root>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Config\Sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml`

2. Set IndexAnonymousContactData to false to disable indexing.

   `<IndexAnonymousContactData>false</IndexAnonymousContactData>`
3. Rebuild the xDB search index.